# Lambda expression in Java?

Tags: c#, java, lambda, closures

I need to switch part of my projects from C# to Java. But before which, I would like to compare two languages carefully and completely.

Regarding to lambda expression, I could write very elegant code via C#, the question is how to implement the same feature gracefully in Java? Thanks in advance!

```
class Program
{
    enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
    class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}, Gender: {3}", Id, Name, Age, Gender);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var students = new[] { 
            new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Nathanial Archibald", Age = 18, Gender = Gender.Male },
            new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Georgina Sparks", Age = 19, Gender = Gender.Female },
            new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Daniel Humphrey", Age = 20, Gender = Gender.Male },
            new Student { Id = 4, Name = "Jenny Humphrey", Age = 17, Gender = Gender.Female },
        };

        var men = students.Where(p => p.Gender == Gender.Male);
        var ageAbove18 = students.Where(p => p.Age > 18);
        var humphrey = students.Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Humphrey"));
        var idGT1orderbyAge = students.Where(p => p.Id > 1).OrderBy(p => p.Age);

        foreach (var s in men) Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        foreach (var s in ageAbove18) Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        foreach (var s in humphrey) Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        foreach (var s in idGT1orderbyAge) Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: java needs time to catch up

Comment: Oh dear :( Not only does Java (7) not have lambda's, but the default collection library (in Java 7) lacks any sort of HoF support - nothing even comparable to LINQ. There are some non-standard libraries that can "help" with those `Where` expressions (in a Java'esque manner), but it'll take some "rewriting the crap by hand" otherwise. I think the better question is **"How is it possible [or least painful] to port this [simple] LINQ/Enumerable code to Java?"** (to avoid the trivial answers, as received).

Comment: I got it, traditional way will be used to write code like above in Java. Anyway, I'm looking forward to the day Java8 comes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lambda expressions of .NET in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775627/lambda-expressions-of-net-in-java)

Comment: Read this article: https://smugjava.blogspot.in/2017/11/lamda-expression-in-java-8.html it wonderfully explains you lambda expression with the example of Behavioural Parameterization concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java in version 8 might support lambda.;)

You can use this [Site](http://functionaljava.org/) or [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-we-need-lambda-expressions).
See this example:

```
final Array<Integer> a = array(1, 2, 3);  
final Array<Integer> b = a.map({int i => i + 42});  
arrayShow(intShow).println(b); // {43,44,45}
```

Comment: Java 8 .. might .. yeah, have fun with that :D (Java is dead to me; I wouldn't consider using it again .. well, not without a significant pay increase.)

Comment: Thanks everybody. Since Java doesn't support lambda currently, I will avoid using this feature and create workaround when needed.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme Java 8 ... does! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Currently java doesn't support Lambda operation, but this will going to be introduced in Java 8.
For further reference [site](http://javapapers.com/core-java/lambda-expression-in-java-8/)

But as you want to switch to Java this is a good option but as long as lambda operation is not supported you can create your methods to do the same task and after java 8 release shift to the lambha operation

[here is an example of lambha operation in java 8](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-lambda-expressions-basics)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 supports Lambda expression. Here is how you can use lambda expression in java to sort a list of Students

```
private static void sort(List<Student> students) {
Comparator<Student> rollNumberComparator = (student1, student2) -> 
    student1.getRollNumber().compareTo(student2.getRollNumber());

Collections.sort(students,rollNumberComparator);
```

}

You can refer :
http://www.groupkt.com/post/088a8dea/lambda-expressions---java-8-feature.htm

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions aren't part of the current version of Java (1.7) it is a feature for Java 8, which wont be released at least until next year

Answer (score -1):

Lambda expression for functional interface

[image]

[image]