# Android Java remove item from list, filter list

Tags: java, android, list

I have a list of locations in my `android` application. I am trying to remove a location from a `list`, where location id equal to a certain value.

**This is my location class:**

```
public class Location{
     Private int locationId;
     Private String locationName;
}
```

So is there a way to remove a location from `List<Location>` without using a `for` or a `while loop`. Something like a `lambda` expression in `C#`:

```
var filteredLocations = locations.Where(x=>x.LocationId!=3).ToList();
```

Comment: Inside your adapter you can make a method with below function    mList.remove(index);
notifyItemRemoved(index);

Comment: Are you tied to a List? A Map<String,Location> would be better in this situation

Comment: As Android does not support Java 8,  you don't have access to most of the lambda oriented APIs. Limited support for lambdas is provided by a third party lib retrolambda. In your case you can either switch to a Map or to a SparseArray or to go with a good old for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the list of array with out using any loop by using the below methods in the adapter

```
//you can use addItem all for adding data in array
    public void addItem(ClassName item) {
            mList.add(item);
            notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);
        }

//delete all for deleting the whole list of data
        public void deleteAll() {
            mList.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

//For deleting a perticular item from data
        public void deleteItem(int index) {
            mList.remove(index);
            notifyItemRemoved(index);

        }

//For adding the whole set of array
        public void addAllItems(List<ClassName> items) {
            mList.addAll(items);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

//For Updating a single item  
        public void updateItem(int index, ClassName item) {
            mList.set(index, item);
            notifyItemChanged(index);
        }
```

Where mList is the Array List

```
public List<ClassName> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in `ArrayList` to directly remove an object.

```
public boolean remove(Object o)
```

You will have to override the equals method for it to work. Internally, it's still gonna iterate over all the objects until it finds the required object.

Here is the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) to the method.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17439325/562840) answer you can see that `lambda` expressions exist in `Java 8`.

Code snippet from the answer:

```
final Array<Integer> a = array(1, 2, 3);  
final Array<Integer> b = a.map({int i => i + 42});  
arrayShow(intShow).println(b); // {43,44,45}
```

`Android` does not suport all `Java 8` features, however `lambda` expressions are suported, as you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
ArrayList<Location> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
arrayList.addAll(list);
arrayList.remove(index) OR arrayList.remove(object)
```